# How to detect the touch on a line drawn in drawrect?

Tags: graph, touch, drawrect

I'm preparing a graph plot application,and i need to detect the touch of the user on the drawn lines using drawRect() method and show an alert message to user with the values at that point.
I have drawn the lines using NSBezierPath.
Is there any way to detect the touch only on the lines ,not at any other places of screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is only to do this is detect the initial and final points if the drawn line and add constraint so that touch will not provide any value except the line .
This can be done using rectangle concepts ,the drawn line will be a diagonal to the rectangle and we can place constraint with according to the rectangle and it's diagonal.